# How to inject an Angular variable into a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this function in my angular controller:

```
$scope.get_all_places = function () {
    $http.get("get-all-places").then(function (response) {
        $scope.selected_place = eval(response.data[0]);
    });
};
```

and i want to set the values i get from `$scope.selected_place` to this JavaScript code :

```
var $shape_options = selected_place.shape_attributes;
var $map_options = selected_place.map_attributes;
switch ($shape_options.shape_type) {
    case 'circle':
        var $center = selected_place.center;
        var $radius = selected_place.radius;
        break;
    case 'rectangle':
        var $bounds = selected_place.rectangle;
        break;
    case 'polygon':
        var $path = selected_place.polygon;
        break;
}
```

but the problem that the JavaScript code executed before the angular get the data from the server.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: why don't you put your javascript code inside get callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place all your code in the `then` function of your ajax call,ajax is executed asynchronously

```
$scope.get_all_places = function () {
    $http.get("get-all-places").then(function (response) {
        $scope.selected_place = eval(response.data[0]);
        var $shape_options = selected_place.shape_attributes;
var $map_options = selected_place.map_attributes;
switch ($shape_options.shape_type) {
    case 'circle':
        var $center = selected_place.center;
        var $radius = selected_place.radius;
        break;
    case 'rectangle':
        var $bounds = selected_place.rectangle;
        break;
    case 'polygon':
        var $path = selected_place.polygon;
        break;
    });
 other_functions($map_options);//call the functions that need the $map_options variable
};
```

Comment: But there is other scripts that need the `map_options` variable

Comment: i don't see any `map_options` variable if you mean `$map_options` then the code that uses that variable has to run in the `then` function as well

Comment: But the code is too large to put it inside the `then` function.

Comment: do you know what a function is and how to use it?

Comment: Yes! but why you asking that?

Comment: Have all your code in a independent function, & execute that function inside then & passing the  $shape_options variable as parameter only.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function:

```
function determineShape(selected_plane){
    var $shape_options = selected_place.shape_attributes;
    var $map_options = selected_place.map_attributes;
    switch ($shape_options.shape_type) {
        case 'circle':
            var $center = selected_place.center;
            var $radius = selected_place.radius;
            break;
        case 'rectangle':
            var $bounds = selected_place.rectangle;
            break;
        case 'polygon':
            var $path = selected_place.polygon;
            break;
    }
}
```

Then call it in the promise response:

```
$scope.get_all_places = function () {
    $http.get("get-all-places").then(function (response) {
        // Run after promise is returned
        determineShape(response.data[0]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Your Variable in jQuery :

**Try this one**

```
var selected_place = $('[ng-controller="your controller name here"]').scope().selected_place;
```

little mistake:

**Try this one Again:**

```
var selected_place = $('[ng-controller="your controller name here"]').scope().get_all_places;
```

Comment: I get this error `Cannot read property 'selected_place' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most tidiest solution but you could put the value into a `hidden` input field and then set that to the JS variable, something like:

```
<input id="selected_place" type="hidden" value="{{ selected_place }}"/>
```

...and the JS

```
document.getElementById("selected_place").value;
```

Comment: I tried it but the java script code executed before the angular get the value.